# Strange output in groovy

Tags: eclipse, groovy

I have just started to learn groovy. I am executing the program below:-

```
class hello {
    static void main(def args)
    {

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))
print "Input:"
int userInput = br.read()
println userInput
for(int i=1;i<10;i++)
{
    int res = userInput + i
    println "$res"
}
    }

}
```

When i am entering any value it is giving strange value of `userInput`. I tried clearing the project and re-execute it. Then i figured out that it is taking the first number and printing its `ASCII value`. Why is it so ? Do i need to typecast ?

I even tried `br.read().toInteger()` but doesn't work.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Print the character value of what is read?

Comment: Yes i want to print the integer value.

Comment: br.read() returns the ascii integer of the read character. You should use readline instead http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#read()

Comment: @unekwu Thanks a lot. It was so basic :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're just reading the first char of the steam as an int ascii value.

Try reading the full line then converting it to an int:

```
int userInput = Integer.parseInt( br.readLine() )
```

More idiomatically, your class becomes (assuming Java 6):

```
class Hello {
    static main( args ) {
        System.console().with { c ->
            int userInput = Integer.parseInt( c.readLine( 'Input : ' ) )
            println userInput

            (1..9).each {
                println userInput + it
            }
        }
    }
}
```